# Generic way to work with something 'unmeasured' in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

**NB**: Don't think about it as a code review, I can imagine socket instead of REST API, or any other source of data. The question is about how to resolve this kind of task in JS-way

I work with some rest API which exposes some items.You can grab items by offset and count. But maximum 1000 at a time. And you cant query the count of items(you can only count them by yourself)

For this kind of work I use code below:

```
const request = require('superagent')
const _ = require('lodash')
const bluebird = require('bluebird')

const STEP = 1000

function call(offset) {
  return bluebird.resolve(
    request
      .get('someapi/items')
      .auth('name', 'key')
      .query({
        offset: offset,
        languagecodes: ['en']
      })
  )
  .then((req) => req.body)
}

function grab(acc, offset) {
  acc = acc || []
  offset = offset || 0
  return call(offset)
    .then((items) => {
      doSomething(items)
      if(items.length < STEP) {
        return
      }
      return grab([], offset + STEP)
    })
}

grab().then(() => {
  finishDo()
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
  throw err
})
```

It works, but has some problems:

- the code is too specific
- If i need any kind of business logic(aggregation, filtering, transformation) I need to put everything inside of `grab` function

So, how can I rewrite this code better?

Comment: You could add a callback to your grab function, just because your using promises doesn't mean you can't still use callbacks.  They work together.  Your callback can also return a promise to keep things promise based.

Comment: Consider instead of using (cities)=>{} syntax, consider passing a function as an argument to grab, such that `return call(offset).then(()=>{referenced_function(cities)})`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added my answer, please check maybe you'll find it useful

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using a callback,

I've also used bluebirds try, this is handy in case you don't return a promise in your callback it will still work, IOW: your callbacks can also be promises if you so wish.

```js
function grab(cb, acc, offset) {
  acc = acc || []
  offset = offset || 0
  return call(offset)
    .then((items) => {
      return bluebird.try(() = > cb(items)).then(() => {
        if(items.length < STEP) {
          return
        }
        return grab(cb, [], offset + STEP)
      })
    })
}

//To use..

grab((items) => { 
  //do something with items.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize what do I want. Actually I can treat API answers as some stream. It provides me an ability to use much the same operations(reduce, filter, map) which I use for collections. 
Below the sample which uses [highland.js](http://highlandjs.org/) to create and handle Node.js streams

```
const H = require('highland');

function grabApi() {
    let offset = 0
    return H(function (push, next) {
      call(offset).then(function(items) {
          push(null, items)
          if(items.length === STEP) {
            offset = offset + STEP
            next()
          } else {
            push(null, H.nil)
          }
      })
    })
};

grabApi() // now it's node-like stream
 .filter(/* some function */)
 .map(/* some function */)
 .each(function(x) { ...
 .done(function() { // when it'll end
```